# how to run svm light in java eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svmlight

I have downloaded the JNI_SVM-light-6.01-64bit version for running svm in Java. I have tried searching online but did not exactly figure out the steps to run the library using eclipse IDE for java. All I want to do is know how to provide an input training file to train the model, and give a test file so that I get the corresponding results? A step by step instruction to do it using eclipse IDE would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hey did you check out the test file? I'm trying it out now myself after importing the library by going to build path > Add External Archives.

You can find the test file here:
http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mtb/svmlight/JNI_SVMLight_Test.java

In the file it creates a random dataset, trains it, calculates the accuracy.. so it's basically giving you the standard operations that you will need.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to run SVMLight from Java code in Eclipse is by using [ClearTK](https://code.google.com/p/cleartk/).  This allows for a standardized way to provide data to and get results from not only SVMLight, but also other models such as CRF.